# How I can get FirestoreDocumentReference into field of type map in CloudFirestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having issues to get my object of type `DocumentReference` in the below explained scenario:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    DocumentReference calRef = db.document(mPath);
    calRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot calSnapshot,
                            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (calSnapshot != null && calSnapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG,calSnapshot.toString());
                DocumentReference dataRef=calSnapshot.getDocumentReference("breviario/oficio");
                if (e != null || dataRef==null) {
                    //launchVolley();
                    return;
                }
                dataRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        mBreviario = dataSnapshot.toObject(Breviario.class);
                        showData();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                //launchVolley();
            }
        }
    });
```

The error i'm having is:

```
2019-12-04 16:36:59.927 5355-5355/org.my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.my.app, PID: 5355
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid field path (breviario/oficio). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:141)
```

The object `calSnapshot` have the data, i can see that in the Log:

```
DocumentSnapshot{
                    key=esp/v2019_2/calendar/2019/12/04, 
                    metadata=SnapshotMetadata
                        {hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=true}, 
                    doc=Document
                        {
                            key=esp/v2019_2/calendar/2019/12/04, 
                            data=ArraySortedMap{
                                (breviario=>ArraySortedMap{(mixto=>liturgia/lh/0/01080104), (oficio=>liturgia/lh/1/01080104)};),            
                                (metaLiturgia=>ArraySortedMap{(fecha=>20191204), (mensaje=>), (salterio=>), (semana=>Semana XXXIV), (tiempo=>07)};)};,  
                            version=SnapshotVersion(seconds=1575473373, nanos=705628000), documentState=SYNCED}
                        }
```

I don't know how i can target the `DocumentReference` in `oficio`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you the `/` is an invalid character for a field.  Nested fields in Firestore are separated by `.`, not `/`.  Use this instead:

```
calSnapshot.getDocumentReference("breviario.oficio");
```

Comment: Right! I thought the separator was `/`. It's working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please accept it as correct (not just upvote).